# Нужно ли тут ставить «итак»?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, смысл

Предложение такое: "Уже хорошо, сейчас **итак** сил должно быть немного".

Comment: Если ставить, то "и так". Итак - это начнём, приступим. Ставить наверное можно, но фраза не понятно о чём вообще, очень бедная и бессодержательная, но может в контексте она точна?

Answer (score 2):

*Нужно ли тут ставить итак?*
Если я правильно поняла смысл предложения, то в нем нужно использовать [**и так**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA) (в значении *и без того*), а конструкцию "должно быть" выделить как вводную.

*— Не ел, но температура снизилась. Он уснул.

**— Уже хорошо, сейчас и так сил, должно быть, немного.** Пусть спит.*

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:
«Зря я это сказал! ― остро пожалел он. ― Ей сейчас **и так** тяжело! Дур-рак!» (Сергей Таранов. Черт за спиной);
Зачем мне была нужна тишина, если у меня ее сейчас **и так** навалом? (Галина Щербакова. Год Алены);
Хотя я сейчас **и так** не очень-то чувствую ее привязанность и уважение (А. И. Дмитриев. Дневник).

[«Итак», «и так»: когда писать слитно, а когда — раздельно](https://mel.fm/gramotnost/gramotny-otvet/7386902-itak-i-tak)

P. S. Точка при цитировании предложения ставится после закрывающих кавычек.